# Firebase Firestore v9 best practices: ignoreUndefinedProperties vs. conditional addDoc/updateDoc

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hey I just updated my project to use Firebase version 9 modular. Now after refactoring code I'm wondering which way is to get desired outcome:
There is a document that has couple required fields (lets say: name, lastName). Now I want to add/update that document but it has multiple fields that are not required.

**What are the best practices to achieve this?** To conditionally add/update [1] or to use "ignoreUndefinedProperties" [2]?

[1]  conditional add/update...

```
if(address){
  await updateDoc(
    doc(db, collection, id), {
      name,
      lastName,
      address,
    })
} else {
  await updateDoc(
    doc(db, collection, id), {
      name,
      lastName,
    })
}
```

[2] ignoreUndefinedProperties...

Also I couldn't find documentation about how to use "ignoreUndefinedProperties" in the new version so could someone guide me to right usage.

**EDIT** (Also is this (adding EDIT) best way to continue and fine down my question? I'm newbie so I'm looking also for StackOverflow best practices)

I'm testing required values but how should I do with values that are not required?
I have multiple collections and +20 calls to them and in many only 2-4 values are required while there might be 20 unrequired values.
This way I get the following error if any of those unrequired values are undefined and in updateDoc()...

```
Function updateDoc() called with invalid data. Unsupported field value: undefined (found in field exampleNotRequiredValue in document ...)
```

So for this case is it better to
[1] check if values are not undefined and in that case add them to update object
[2] use *ignoreUndefinedProperties* (as isn't this the point of this setting doesn't this do this check automatically and I don't need to change many functions?)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`"ignoreUndefinedProperties"` may not be the best option. If name is required but is undefined for any reason, then it won't be written to the document. You can write security rules that'll check if `name` and `nickname` fields are present but it'll be best to conditionally add fields to your update object and make sure the required fields are present.

In case you want to use `ignoreUndefinedProperties`, you would have to use `initializeFirestore` instead of `getFirestore`:

```js
import { initializeFirestore } from "firebase/firestore"

const db = initializeFirestore(app, {ignoreUndefinedProperties: true})
```

Comment: Why is it better to add fields conditionally to update object than just using ignoreUndefinedProperties, because doesn't the ignore setting automatically just lesser the code needed to be written?

Comment: @Hessuew I've explained that in answer already. If the 'name' which is required is undefined for any reason then it won't be added in document. So technically it's not a required field then unless you add a check that it is defined, then using `ignoreUndefinedProperties` should not be an issue.

Comment: Ah you are right, I asked with wrong point of question (ofcourse required fields should be checked they are present and have value). I will add forward question to my original question as Edit to point out what I'm meaning